# Скрыть расширение файлов.php

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

У меня страница есть все проблемы решены, теперь у меня есть файлы некоторых назову: index.php contact.php reg.php gallery.php когда кто то вошел на сайт там на навигации например Галлерея там адрес сайта:www.domain.ml/gallery.php как скрыть .php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

если в корне приложения нет файла .htaccess то создайте его и впишите туда

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

если такой файл есть то добавьте правило

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Спасибо вам! Блогадарю!